# How to mic a flute for live performance

Tags: performing, flute, microphones

Would you place the mic at the mouthpiece or the end of the flute?

Comment: I'm no flute player (I do play a bit of Irish whistle) so I'll leave this as a comment. My thought was that the sound comes from the mouthpiece and the opening after the last covered hole (which varies depending the note played) so you should mike the mouthpiece. Googling images for "flute microphone" tends to confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

Flautists love to sway around as they play; it’s rare to see a flautist not do that. It causes uneven volume and, when they move past the mic, phase problems.

I used to use a small diaphragm condenser mic and ask them not to move. That makes musicians nervous, impedes their performance, and they do it anyway.

The best solution I’ve found is a mic intended for flute. It attaches to the flute at the mouthpiece end, which is where you want it, and stays in place no matter how much movement there is. The one I use is an Audix ADX10-FLP, for both for live performance and recording.

Comment: Applause for fitting the tool to the performer rather than the other way around.  Another option is to replace the head joint cap with one containing a piezo element, usually hardwired to the amp.  Maybe there are some radio/bluetooth options these days.

Comment: Totally true. For flute in particular, fixing the head position will also throw many players off from properly intonating.

Answer (score 3):

Since the sound emanates from the mouthpiece itself, it makes sense to have that close to the mic. Although the end furthest away has a hole, the sound doesn't come out from there. Very simple to put one's ear in certain places while a flute is being played, and the answer is there for all to hear.

Answer (score 2):

The standard 'Rock' way to mic a flute is with a SM58 in the same position as if the player was singing.   Certainly not at the open end.   For 'classical' stick a stereo pair a few feet back.  Or whatever else is appropriate for the room and the musical context.

[image]